# Count negative numbers in list using list comprehension

Tags: functional-programming

Working through the first edition of "Introduction to Functional Programming", by Bird & Wadler, which uses a theoretical lazy language with Haskell-ish syntax.

Exercise 3.2.3 asks:

> Using a list comprehension, define a function for counting the number
>   of negative numbers in a list

Now, at this point we're still scratching the surface of lists. I would assume the intention is that only concepts that have been introduced at that point should be used, and the following have **not** been introduced yet:

- A function for computing list length
- List indexing
- Pattern matching i.e. f (x:xs) = ...
- Infinite lists
- All the functions and operators that act on lists - with one exception - e.g. ++, head, tail, map, filter, zip, foldr, etc

What tools are available?

- A maximum function that returns the maximal element of a numeric list
- List comprehensions, with possibly multiple generator expressions and predicates
- The notion that the output of the comprehension need not depend on the generator expression, implying the generator expression can be used for controlling the size of the generated list
- Finite arithmetic sequence lists i.e. [a..b] or [a, a + step..b]

I'll admit, I'm stumped. Obviously one can extract the negative numbers from the original list fairly easily with a comprehension, but how does one then count them, with no notion of length or indexing?

The availability of the maximum function would suggest the end game is to construct a list whose maximal element is the number of negative numbers, with the final result of the function being the application of maximum to said list.

I'm either missing something blindingly obvious, or a smart trick, with a horrible feeling it may be the former. Tell me SO, how do you solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My old -- and very yellowed copy of the first edition has a note attached to Exercise 3.2.3: "This question needs # (length), which appears only later". The moral of the story is to be more careful when setting exercises. I am currently finishing a third edition, which contains answers to every question.

By the way, did you answer Exercise 1.2.1 which asks for you to write down all the ways that
square (square (3 + 7)) can be reduced to normal form. It turns out that there are 547 ways!

Comment: Well, that answer came from a more authoritative source than I had any right to expect!

Comment: To expand after an errant enter keypress: I'm glad I wasn't missing anything obvious - I'm using the text as a refresher, and was aware of the standard toolbox one would normally have for lists, but wanted to answer in the context of the pedagogy of the book.  I realised though in §2.3, you introduced strings, and assumed existence of a width function - length by another name of course - and in §3.1 revealed strings to be lists of characters, so arguably it could be answered with a list comprehension that produces a string of equivalent length!

Comment: With regards to 1.2.1, I confess to being lazy and not fully computing the results of the combinatorial explosion from the from the many ternary and quaternary integer multiplications that appear.

Comment: I think he means "Thinking Functionally with Haskell" which came out in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be assuming too many restrictions - taking the length of the filtered list seems like the blindingly obvious solution to me.

An couple of alternatives but both involve using some other function that you say wasn't introduced:

```
sum [1 | x <- xs, x < 0]

maximum (0:[index | (index, ()) <- zip [1..] [() | x <- xs, x < 0]])
```